# Is there a way to copy 32bit VS Code extensions and settings to 64bit VS Code on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, 32bit-64bit, windows-11

I have installed different VS Code extensions with associated settings on my VS Code 32bit. Now I need to install the VS Code 64bit version after uninstalling the 32bit version. I would like to install VS Code 64bit while keeping my existing extension settings.

Because, 32-bit OEM support has been dropped with Windows 10, version 2004. The last stable VS Code version to support Windows 32-bit is 1.83 (September 2023).
So I need to install a 64-bit release.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

VS Code settings, user-defined keybindings, and user-defined snippets are stored in an architecture-independent location. They are not removed upon uninstallation of VS Code. I believe that if you uninstall your 32bit VS Code and install a 64bit version, those will continue being applied without you needing to do anything.

Extensions are stored within the user home directory in .vscode/extensions/. This is not so black and white. Some extensions have platform/architecture-specific binaries (such as the C++ extension), but I'm not exactly sure whether which binary gets used depends on the VS Code binary's architecture through which the extension was installed, or the host's preferred architecture. I'd just say try doing nothing and see if it works. But if your machine supports both 64bit and 32bit binaries, then it shouldn't really matter unless you actually care which architecture gets used for extensions as well, in which case that's something you'll need to work out on a case-by-case basis. The extension's marketplace page should have a download button that allows you to select target platforms and architectures where applicable.

Comment: Thank you for the help and I got a path. 
What I just did was, I saw a button on VS Code settings -> Settings which can Sync the setting to the GitHub account.  Then I Sync it first & uninstall the existing 32-bit version. Then installed the 64-bit version. Now I can see all previous extensions and settings. This saved my time.

Comment: Platform dependent bits are typically runtime binaries, debuggers and so on. Those were usually downloaded the first time an extension is activated but now packed inside the extension itself.